# AJAX post is empty on the server side (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am making an AJAX request to a PHP controller, by using jQuery ajax, but when trying to get the posted data with PHP the $_POST is empty. Below is the actual function:

```
function GetSeriesForManufacturer(manuf) {
    selectedmanufacturer = manuf;
    //Make an AJax Call For Getting Series Of Manufacturer
    var series = null;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: "{manufacturer:'" + selectedmanufacturer + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json", //; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            //remove loading gif
            $(".loading").hide();
            //Append Data
            AppendSeries($.parseJSON(response.text), selectedmanufacturer);
            //Custom Scrollbar Call
            $('.MatchingSeries ul').mCustomScrollbar();                        
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {  }
    });                         
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `url` defined?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I just replaced teh actual url with "url", the post is happening normally, as I can see in the firebug console.

Comment: The problem is likely this line: `data: "{manufacturer:'" + selectedmanufacturer + "'}",`. Either a string or an object, not a string that has the JS representation of an object. Try `data: {manufacturer: selectedmanufacturer},` instead.

Comment: @Panos It wasn't an answer, it was a question. I just wanted to make sure it wasn't something that blindingly obvious before I spent any time looking at it properly ;)

Comment: Has there are any error in your console??

Comment: No there are no errors. And the data appear as below: JSON: manufacturer
 "BROTHER", Source
{manufacturer:'BROTHER'}

Comment: @Anthony Grist, I tried your suggestion, but nothing has changed, apart the way the JSON is formatted.

Comment: Panos, to speak with someone here, use the at symbol, e.g. @AnthonyGrist. They will get an inbox icon to show you've replied to them.

Comment: A question from a user who cannot yet comment: "Can you tell me you are working on windows or linux and also tell me on live server or localhost?".

Comment: @Ankit vadariya  Of course, its a live test server, Debian, and I am on a windows PC.

Comment: Try getting rid of the `contentType: "application/json"` line and set it using a `header()` in the PHP script being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to stringify data. Just send object literal is ok.

```
data: {manufacturer: selectedmanufacturer},
```

Second, you don't need this line:

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will fix it... (just beat me to it as well) - threw the code up on a local dev box and getting rid of the `contentType` line solved the problem on my version.

Comment: @Leo Deng I have tried removing contentType: "application/json", as it was suggested on a similar thread before I post, but nothing changed. But combining this with the data modifications appears to be working, I ll accept the answer in a minute. Thank you, and everyone who replied in this post.

Comment: @Panos this is trick. once I also tried to stringify object before sending data, and finally found jQuery is handling that.

Answer (score 0):

Let jQuery do the encoding for you:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {
       manufacturer: selectedmanufacturer
    },
    contentType: "application/json", //; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        ...
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {  }});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seems to change anything. But thank you in any case!